# Persisting DOM en cache problems using Selenium on SlickGrid

Tags: selenium, slickgrid

I'm testing (using Selenium) a site containing a slickgrid.
To find the correct field to enter a value, I have to apply a filter, and then double click the field to enter the data.
The problem is, that after applying the filter nine out of ten times Selenium ends up with an exception that the element is no longer attached to the DOM, or is not present in the cache anymore. One out of ten doesn't fail on this point.
I've tried about every bit of advice I can find on this issue, but none has brought any sufficient help. Waiting an looping until the element is present, visible etc. doesn't work.
So: is there a way to have Selenium locate an element in a slickgrid after the page has changed because of a filter action?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using WebDriver or the IDE?  If you are using WebDriver, are you using PageObjects?  I've seen issues like this appear using PageObjects when it tries to fetch something after it's referenced earlier in a script

Comment: I'm using the FireFox WebDriver. But I don't use PageObjects, I think. It's quite straightforward Selenium, recognizing elements with driver.FindElement. Seems like SlickGrid shows elements faster than that they appear in the DOM, so Selenium can't pick them up. I've tried all sorts of waits, sleeps and loops, but neither has brought any help.